# The LINQ expression node type 'NewArrayBounds' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, arrays, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

```
 select new ProviderMeta
            {
                LoginId = user.LoginId,
                AgencyId = user.AgencyId,
                Application = user.Application,
                UserId = user.UserId,
                Name = agencySnapshot.Name,
                Roles = new int[0],
                Cluster = app.ClusterId ?? 0,
                Created = app.Created,
                TitleType = user.TitleType,
                Feature = (foundFeature == null ? 0 : foundFeature.Feature)
            }).ToList();
```

Here, Roles is an integer array but it is not letting me assign an empty array 
  with zero.
  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty array with zero?" Are you asking for an empty, zero-length integer array, or an integer array with a single element of value zero?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. its integer array with a single element of value zero

Comment: Then you need `new int[1]` or perhaps `new int[] { 0 }` ? I can still see it not being supported if your LINQ is being translated to a SQL query, though it seems to work for me in LINQ to SQL. You could try creating a temporary variable (`var emptyRoles = new int[] { 0 };`) and use that.

Comment: Terminate the EF query with ToList() or AsEmumerable() before projecting into a custom type with untranslatable expressions.

Comment: @octavioccl Hey adding constructor works later. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Sumi, got it I knew I have solved that problem that way, thanks for confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the array in an empty constructor of your class:

```
public class ProviderMeta
{
    //...
   public ProviderMeta()
   {
     Roles = new int[]{0};
   }
}
```

And remove it from the projection

```
 select new ProviderMeta
        {
            LoginId = user.LoginId,
            AgencyId = user.AgencyId,
            Application = user.Application,
            UserId = user.UserId,
            Name = agencySnapshot.Name,
            //Roles = new int[0], remove this line
            Cluster = app.ClusterId ?? 0,
            Created = app.Created,
            TitleType = user.TitleType,
            Feature = (foundFeature == null ? 0 : foundFeature.Feature)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry its not working. I believe its a problem in Linq rather than constructer.

Comment: but did you remove the array initialization in the query  projection?

Comment: yeah I did asap after you suggested that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can select an empty array with initialization: `new string[] {}`

This works the same as when selecting an array with items:

```
 IList<Bar> empty = context.Foo.Select(foo => new Bar
 {
     // ...
     Roles = new int[] {},
     // ...
 }).ToList();

 IList<Bar> withRoles = context.Foo.Select(foo => new Bar
 {
     // ...
     Roles = new [] { 1, 2, 3},
     // ...
 }).ToList();
```