# Error from Entity Framework setting byte array in linq to entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm getting an exception in my linq to entity query that says

> The LINQ expression node type 'NewArrayBounds' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

when I try and get the 'RegisteredInstructorImage'

Here is what I'm doing to get the error

```
.Select(i => new EventResult
            {
                IsInstructorRegistered = i.RegisteredInstructor == null ? false : true,
                RegisteredInstructorId = i.RegisteredInstructor != null ? i.RegisteredInstructor.YogaProfileId : 0,
                RegisteredInstructorName = i.RegisteredInstructor != null ? i.RegisteredInstructor.FirstName : "",
                RegisteredInstructorImage = i.RegisteredInstructor != null ? i.RegisteredInstructor.PrimaryImage11 : new byte[0],
                RegisteredInstructorTotalReviews = i.RegisteredInstructor != null ? i.RegisteredInstructor.TotalReviews : 0,

            }).ToPagedList(Page, 10);
```

In `EventResult`, I'm initializing it like below according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856228/the-linq-expression-node-type-newarraybounds-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entit) which didn't effect my result I'm still getting the error. Did I do something wrong here?

```
public class EventResult
{
    public EventResult()
    {
        RegisteredInstructorImage = new byte[] { 0 };
    }
    public byte[] RegisteredInstructorImage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One option would be to add a `RegisteredInstructor` property to your `EventResult`. Then make `RegisteredInstructorName` property read-only (and reading from `RegisteredInstructor.FirstName`) and much the same for the other properties.

Comment: I think the best solution is this. i.RegisteredInstructor.PrimaryImage11 ?? null and I can set the byte[] to a nullable byte?[]

Comment: `i.RegisteredInstructor.PrimaryImage11 ?? null` is pointless. (since `??` would convert `null` to, ahem, `null`) `i.RegisteredInstructor?.PrimaryImage11` is better. Also, arrays are nullable by default.

Comment: EF provider cannot create SQL from the arbitrary .Net function. That's what the error says. You should search for "LINQ expression node type is not supported" to see more details and possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing:

```
i.RegisteredInstructor != null ? i.RegisteredInstructor.PrimaryImage11 : new byte[0]
```

to:

```
i.RegisteredInstructor?.PrimaryImage11
```

*Then consider changing the property setter for `RegisteredInstructorImage` so that it checks for `null` (and changes to an empty array) if you desire.*

Comment: this syntax looks incorrect and gives me a red line under it

Comment: What version of C# are you using? What is the compiler error message?  @user1186050

Comment: I just created a VM in Azure using 2016 Data Center and the it came pre installed with VS 2017, so I assume it's the most current, whichever that is...